# hadoop dfs -ls gives list of folders not present in the local file system

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have just installed a standalone cluster on my laptop. On running the `hdfs dfs -ls` command in a terminal, I get to see a list of folders. Upon searching the local file system through the File Explorer window I couldn't locate those files in my file system.

```
rishirich@localhost:/$ hdfs dfs -ls
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - rishirich supergroup          0 2017-11-09 03:32 user
```

This folder named 'user' was nowhere to be seen on the local filesystem. Is it that the folder is hidden?

If so, then what terminal command should I use in order to find this folder?
If not, then how do I locate it?

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls gives you list of files and directories in your HDFS not your local file system, so the user directory is in you HDFS not local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see the hdfs directory structure in graphical view to view it you have to use your terminal only.
    `hdfs dfs -ls /`
and to see local file directory structure in the terminal you should try
     `ls <path>`
     `cd <path>`
cd use to change the directory in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In your installation of Hadoop, you had set up a core-site.xml file to establish the `fs.defaultFS` property. If you did not make this `file://`, it will not be the local filesystem.

If you set it to `hdfs://`, then the default locations for the namenode and datanode directories are in your local `/tmp` folder.

Note - those are HDFS blocks, not whole, readable files stored in HDFS.

If you want to list your local filesystem, you're welcome to use `hadoop fs -ls file://`